# How to fix gap between foundation and brick siding

Tags: foundation, outdoor, siding, gap

First time homeowner here and trying to find how to seal the gap between foundation and siding wall in a split-level 1950s built home.

I Was originally planning to fill the gap with insulating spray foam and patch it on top with ready mix stucco patch and repair, textured stucco patch. Can the experienced folks please chime in and guide considering it's outside the house and I may need to take care of humidity escape, vermin deterrence etc.

[image: foundation_gap]

Comment: Just to make sure there are not more issues (structural) with the foundation, you might want to talk to a mason first.

Comment: @Armand - any reason that you suspect structural issues with the foundation? want to engage a mason with specific question, instead of an open-ended inspection. also I did hire an inspector before closing who did not identify any structural issues.

Comment: ah, inspector is fine. I just get worried about why concrete/masonry is crumbling and it's hard to tell from the photo if it's just a bit of edge issue or something that could extend deeper like bad mortar.